# How can I tell if a materialized view refresh will be full refresh or incremental refresh?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, materialized-views

According to the Redshift docs on [materialized view refreshes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/materialized-view-refresh-sql-command.html), there are many rules specified for the kinds of query logic that disallow incremental refreshes of materialized views. However, while working with a materialized view, I can find no way to empirically confirm whether or not a potential refresh will be full or incremental using something like `explain`. Is there any way to test for refresh types on MVs within Redshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `state` column in the STV_MV_INFO table will tell you if an existing mv can be incrementally updated or has to be recomputed in full.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_MV_INFO.html

Comment: How can we do this in serverless cluster? It cannot find above table.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. The console output following MV creation will specify if an incrementally maintained MV could not be created, including the reason why.